# apache mpm in Fedora Linux

Tags: apache, fedora

What is ideal configuration of apache - Prefork or Worker in Fedora Linux run on 8 core cpu with 60gb RAM for heavy traffic sites, Currently configured in httpd.conf -

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
    StartServers       8
    MinSpareServers    5
    MaxSpareServers   20
    ServerLimit      3500
    MaxClients       3500
    MaxRequestsPerChild  40000
</IfModule>

<IfModule worker.c>
  StartServers         4
  MaxClients         3500
  MinSpareThreads     25
  MaxSpareThreads     75 
  ThreadsPerChild     25
  MaxRequestsPerChild  40000
</IfModule>
```

Currently prefork is active.

Answer (score 0):

Webservers do not scale well. Unless you have a *very* unusual workload you will get better throughput and capacity and much, *much* more resillience out of 2 servers with 2 cores and 8Gb of RAM than this box - but a lot depends on what your workload looks like and what else is running on the machine.

If you have a look around the site you'll see that questions about capacity planning are closed as being too broad, or moved to serverfault (where they are [closed as duplicates](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning) to a question where there is no definitive answer).

Hence the answer is to [measure what traffic your hardware can cope with](http://lampe2e.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/accurate-capacity-planning-with-apache.html) and set the limits accordingly.